# R project: maps package

Tags: r, maps

I am new to R so this may be stupid to ask. I am using maps package to plot point in US map. However the map that appears after using:

```
 map("state", lwd=1, col="#cccccc")
```

is very small in size. How can I increase the size of the map. I went through the manual but nothing I found could solve my issue.

Comment: The graphic that calling the function creates in the device window has nothing to do with the size of the output. You can use any host of functions, like `png` or `pdf` to create outputs of any size you choose.

Comment: I see you haven't accepted any answers to your questions. If someone answers your question it is courteous to accept their answer. Glad I could help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try outputting the map to a file, for example:

```
png("example.png",width=60,height=60,units="in",res=75)
map("state", lwd=1, col="#cccccc")
graphics.off()
```

creates a 60"x60" map at 75 dpi. You can change the parameters of the function you use to output the graphic to specify the size and resolution.